# Golang http.Get displays error EOF in Container

Tags: docker, go, ca

I have a golang script that calls an HTTP API. Everything works great when I run it on my development computer. Once I create the container and run it I get an EOF at the end of the URL on panic. I have read a lot of issues like this and have tried everyone I see. I added a ca-certificates.crt from my host machine to the container to /etc/ssl/certs/. I set the request close to true, I have disabled Keep-Alive and Compression. All of these steps worked for others on other posts. Any help appreciated.

I got my certfile from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bagder/ca-bundle/master/ca-bundle.crt

I am running go version go1.9.2 darwin/amd64 and the container is on a ubuntu 16.04 host.

```
client := &http.Client{Timeout: 30 * time.Second, Transport: &http.Transport{
    DisableCompression:true,
    DisableKeepAlives:  true,
}}

url := "https://myapiurl.com"
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(mybodybytes))
req.Close = true
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    log.Panic(err) // Panics Here
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
...
```

Dockerfile:

```
 FROM scratch

    ADD ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/

    ADD myservice /
    CMD ["/myservice"]
```

Comment: Check the traffic with tcpdump/wireshark first, to see what exactly was sent and received. Then compare with the traffic gathered after you run the same program from your host machine.

Comment: So what's the error string returned exactly? Is mybodybytes empty? Can you perform a get request (this is a post)?

Comment: Can you update this with the error message you see? Perhaps the client is failing due to the certificate not being signed. You can disable certificate checking (at your own risk) in the client by configuring the transport.

Comment: how do you start docker container ? do you expose ports ?

Comment: I figured it out. Not sure if it's a bug or not. If I connect using TLS in the gRPC service with the encrypted overlay docker network I get that error. If I connect using grpc.WithInsecure() I don't get the error and the results come back just fine - Am I doubling on TLS?